# Not able to install Maven on Linux

Tags: linux, maven

I am trying to install Maven on Linux as I have extracted tar file also in my directory where I wanted to and also setup the environment variables but when I check mvn --version then it complains mvn:command not found.
Can anybody tell me reason.

Comment: You have added the bin Directory of the maven Distribution to the PATH variable?

Comment: export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3

export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

Comment: this also   export PATH=$M2:$PATH

Comment: Do not use M2_HOME anymore is deprecated only PATH entry is needed. And of course JAVA_HOME needed to be set correctly. That's it.

Comment: @khmarbaise then what should i use instead of M2_HOME ?

Comment: any suggestions.

Comment: All of these variables you should set in .bashrc or corresponding file. This way you will have them set for each bash opened. Try also to go into $M2_HOME/bin directory and run the maven from there. 
`./mvn --version`

Comment: Thanks alot @FilMiOs ..It worked now :) thank you so much

Comment: I just posted my comment as an answer. Please mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

All of these variables you should set in `.bashrc` or corresponding file. This way you will have them set for each bash/terminal/shell opened. Try also to go into `$M2_HOME/bin` directory and run the maven from there. `./mvn --version`